# Injecting/passing components as props from HOC to the Wrapped-Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, functional-programming, higher-order-components

In my recent React project I have used some HOC's to pass component as props to the wrappedcomponent and I was wondering if there is anything thing wrong with this approach. Below is an example:

**HOC:**

```
import AnotherComponent from './a'

function withExampleComponent(WrappedComponent){
 render(){
     const exampleComp = <ExampleComponent someprops={value} />
     return( 
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} exampleComponent={exampleComp} />
     )
   }
}
```

And here is the component that uses the above HOC

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
       const {exampleComponent} = this.props
       return(
           <div>
              {exampleComponent}
           </div>
        )
     }
}
export default withExampleComponent(MainComponent)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in withExampleComponent you are missing to return a component definition. According react site https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html. you should return something like

```
import AnotherComponent from './a'

function withExampleComponent(WrappedComponent){
 return class extends React.Component {
     render(){
         const exampleComp = <ExampleComponent someprops={value} />
         return( 
            <WrappedComponent {...this.props} exampleComponent={exampleComp} />
         )
       }
    }
}
```

and to use with MainComponent

```
export default withExampleComponent(MainComponent);
```

Comment: Thank you - you are right about the componet definition. But i still wonder if there are any issues with this pattern (injecting component to wrappedcomponent), as I have not been able to find such example. According to React Docs, one usually passes state values or instance methods. But is it an anti pattern if one passes a component?

Comment: No, I believe it is not a problem. I myself usually use that way also. I think it is similar to the pattern render function